# Make a simple bot for telegram forwarding

Tags: twitter, filtering, chatbot, telegram-bot

I'm a student trying to make a bot for telegram.
I've tried it using google, but it was really hard for me to make it.
What I want to make are 2 bots, helping me collecting information.

1. Auto forwarding from telegram channel or group(I'm not a host) to my channel or group
2. Auto forwarding from twitter to my telegram but forwarding after filtering a keyword that I set

I tried IFTTT already but there was no solution for forwarding channel to channel, and filtering a keyword while forwarding from twitter.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use MTPROTO to access full potentials of Telegram's API, since bots are a limited version of the real MTPROTO API and they don't give you the full potentiality for your kind of work, which is crawling.

One of the good MTPROTO libraries out there is written in python and it's called [Telethon](https://pypi.org/project/Telethon/).

You can get an idea from this source code which is written in Telethon:

```py
api_id = "YOUR API ID HERE"
api_hash = "YOUR API HASH HERE"

client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

to_copy_groups = {
    from_group_id_here: to_group_id_here,
}

@client.on(event=events.NewMessage)
async def message_handler(event):
    from_id = None
    chat_type = None
    if isinstance(event.peer_id, PeerChat):
        from_id = event.peer_id.chat_id
        chat_type = "Chat"
    elif isinstance(event.peer_id, PeerChannel):
        from_id = event.peer_id.channel_id
        chat_type = "Channel"
    if from_id is not None and from_id in to_copy_groups:
        if to_copy_groups[from_id] in groups:
            if chat_type == "Chat":
                await event.forward_to(PeerChat(to_copy_groups[from_id]))
            if chat_type == "Channel":
                await event.forward_to(PeerChannel(to_copy_groups[from_id]))
    return
```